# D3.js advanced node connections (find the path)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, search

I`m looking for advice or some ideas.
I need to build some D3 chart (looks like organization chart) but with some advanced feature. Some nodes must be connected with another node(s) with a path connection. It looks like on a [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1Vm6.png). Those lines should be separated (each connection - different line).

What I thought to do: Make additional points with some margin for each node, and build a path based on those points ([visual in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrEuT.png)) and add some padding for each separate line.

I can't choose another type of chart.

My current graph look's like in here: https://blog.zubasoft.at/Examples/D3.js/OrgChart/

Any ideas about how to make such type of connections?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to create a [path](https://github.com/d3/d3-path) for each connection. In your visual for example, you would move the connection 5 pixels to the right, then 10 to the bottom, then move to the right till u reach the center of the target node, then move up.

Making these rules wouldn't be too bad if you have fixed vertical and horizontal margins for the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find the intersection between two lines but the formulla is quite complicated see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection

You can use the demo bellow as starting point

```js
    var chart = new OrgChart(document.getElementById("tree"), {
        template: "ula",
        layout: BALKANGraph.mixed,
        mouseScroolBehaviour: BALKANGraph.none,
        scaleInitial: BALKANGraph.match.boundary,
        nodeBinding: {
            field_0: "name",
            field_1: "title",
            img_0: "img"
        },
        nodes: [
            { id: 1, name: "Jack Hill", title: "Chairman and CEO", email: "amber@domain.com", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/1.jpg" },
            { id: 2, pid: 1, name: "Lexie Cole", title: "QA Lead", email: "ava@domain.com", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/2.jpg" },
            { id: 3, pid: 1, name: "Janae Barrett", title: "Technical Director", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/3.jpg" },
            { id: 4, pid: 1, name: "Aaliyah Webb", title: "Manager", email: "jay@domain.com", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/4.jpg" },
            { id: 5, pid: 2, name: "Elliot Ross", title: "QA", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/5.jpg" },
            { id: 6, pid: 2, name: "Anahi Gordon", title: "QA", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/6.jpg" },
            { id: 7, pid: 2, name: "Knox Macias", title: "QA", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/7.jpg" },
            { id: 8, pid: 3, name: "Nash Ingram", title: ".NET Team Lead", email: "kohen@domain.com", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/8.jpg" },
            { id: 9, pid: 3, name: "Sage Barnett", title: "JS Team Lead", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/9.jpg" },
            { id: 10, pid: 8, spids: [2], name: "Alice Gray", title: "Programmer & QA", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/10.jpg" },
            { id: 11, pid: 8, name: "Anne Ewing", title: "Programmer", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/11.jpg" },
            { id: 12, pid: 9, name: "Reuben Mcleod", title: "Programmer", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/12.jpg" },
            { id: 13, pid: 9, name: "Ariel Wiley", title: "Programmer", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/13.jpg" },
            { id: 14, pid: 4, name: "Lucas West", spids: [1], title: "Marketer", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/14.jpg" },
            { id: 15, pid: 4, name: "Adan Travis", title: "Designer", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/15.jpg" },
            { id: 16, pid: 4, name: "Alex Snider", title: "Sales Manager", img: "https://balkangraph.com/js/img/16.jpg" }
        ]
    });
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#tree {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://balkangraph.com/js/latest/OrgChart.js"></script>

<div id="tree"></div>
```